# Resize UIImage to 100% and crop

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have a landscape `UIImage` that I want to crop to 900x900 size.

I don't want it to be stretched - I want it to scale it to 100% - the image will be scaled to fit 900x900, and the part of the image that is out of bounds will be cropped.

I've tried this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, UIScreen.main.scale);
image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage!
```

But all it does is stretching the image to fit 900x900 size, that's not what I want.

Any idea what can I do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop from center of the image to 900 pixel if the image size is larger than 900.

**Here is the code :**

```
func centerCropImage(image1:UIImage) -> UIImage
{

    let modifiedSize:CGFloat = 900.0;
    // Center the crop area

    let clippedRect = CGRect(x: ((image.size.width - modifiedSize)/2), y: ((image.size.height - modifiedSize)/2), width: modifiedSize, height: modifiedSize);


    // Crop logic
    let imageRef:CGImage = image.cgImage!.cropping(to: clippedRect)!;

    //(image as! CGImage).cropping(to: clippedRect)!;
    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef);

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Hope it helps

Happy coding ...

Comment: And if it doesn't? How can I find the closest size to 900x900 (square) to crop to!

Comment: Sorry I did not get your point. Do you mean to crop to 900 only if the image size (both width and height) is greater than 900??

Comment: no. If for example the image is 320x556 so what will be the largest resolution to crop to a square?

Comment: Definitely 320 would be the largest resolution. As larger than 320 will stretch the image width wise. So in that case just check the width and height , if both are greater than 900 then use modifiedSize as 900, else find the minimum of width and height of image size and assign it to modifiedSize. code : min(image.size.width, image.size.height)

Comment: Pleasure to help.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you can achieve what you want by tailoring the contentMode property of a UIImageView (which you attach your image to).

Take a look at the developer reference here : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview

However, to answer your question, to put the image in the center of a UIImageView without stretching it, use contentMode.center ; to scale it to fit the view but maintain the aspect ratio use .aspectFit ; and to stretch to fit the image view use .scaleToFill. There are other options explained in the link.